# Query fails when run via Visual Studio, works fine elsewhere

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, db2

I receive this error:

> [DB2/6000] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

whenever I run a query via a visual studio project in vb.net. If I run the same query via Open Office Base, it takes a long time but it works. How do I go about troubleshooting whats causing this?

Comment: Is this ALL  queries or one in particular?

Comment: I've only queried this dbase a couple of times and other queries have worked. This is easily the largest of them so I'm assuming its getting cut off for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to @Tom H's answer. I had a timeout issue to. The only thing that worked for me is:

```
iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sqlStatement, conn);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give that a shot once I figure out how to use it. :)

Answer (score 3):

That SQLSTATE code indicates a user interruption. It could be caused by a timeout. Check the timeout settings in your Visual Studio project for that particular connection and see if increasing it helps.

Since it's DB2, you might also need to take a look for the `db2cli.ini` file and increase the `QUERYTIMEOUT INTERVAL` there.

Comment: db2cli.ini has: QUERYTIMEOUTINTERVAL=0. I set Connection Timeout=0; at the end of my connection string but it did not help.